# What is the purpose of the using statement?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, using-statement, try-finally

On the basis of what is written on this [web page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/it-it/library/yh598w02%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), and if I understand correctly, the `using` statement works like a `try/finally`, so I might mistakenly expect that if an exception occurs in a `using` statement, it should not crash the program.

However, when the `DownloadString` method, shown in the example below, throws a `WebException`, the program crashes.

```
using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
{
    string response = client.DownloadString(url);
    // ...
}
```

This is normal, since the `using` statement does not work like a `try/catch/finally`, then actually no exception is handled. But then I wonder what is the purpose of the `using` statement.

**UPDATE...** Based on responses below, I add the following considerations. Basically, if I need to handle an exception, possible solutions could be as follows.

1. Put the `using` statement inside a `try/catch` block.
2. Put only the `DonwloadString` method inside a `try/catch` block.
3. Write manually a try/catch/finally block as in the following code sample.

Sample code for the third solution.

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
try
{
    string response = client.DownloadString(url);
    // ...
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    // handle (or ignore) the exception
}
finally
{
    if (client != null)
        client.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: It calls the Dispose method for you.

Comment: `using` may not act like a `try/catch/finally` but it certainly does act like a `try/finally{dispose()}`

Comment: The using statement ensures that Dispose is called even if an exception occurs while you are calling methods on the object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> if I understand correctly, the using statement works like a try/finally

Correct.

> so I would expect that if an exception occurs in a using statement, it should not crash the program.

Incorrect.

Neither `try/finally` nor `using` statements swallow exceptions - if you don't catch the exception, it will propagate up. If it's uncaught, it will usually terminate the process. (There are a few cases where it won't, based on which thread it's in and how the CLR is configured, but that's a different matter.)

> But then I wonder what is the purpose of the using statement.

To make it simpler to write code that needs to dispose of resources. That's all. If we didn't have `using` statements, we'd have a *lot* of `try`/`finally` blocks which just called `Dispose`... and that would be considerably uglier. (Been there, done that - that was Java until Java 7 introduced the try-with-resources statement.)

Comment: So, I should put the `using` block inside a `try/catch` block, or write a `try/catch/finally{dispose()}` block... Which one of these two solutions is to be preferred?

Comment: @enzom83: Either is fine - whichever you find easier to read. Personally I prefer using the `using` statement either inside or outside a `try`/`catch`; the `using` part makes it easy to see that I'm disposing of the resource, without having to check the contents of a `finally` block.

Answer (score 3):

A `using` statement doesn't make all exceptions magically disappear, it just means that the `IDisposable.Dispose` method is correctly called on the `client` object if one does occur. This is important for making sure that any unmanaged resources are released.

It will rethrow any exceptions that occur, and you'll still have to handle them in your own code.

Answer (score 0):

[See MSDN description of `using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx)

In short, using ensures that `.Dispose()` is called even if exception occurs.  It does not however stop the exception from doing its thing.

Answer (score 0):

The using statement does NOT have a catch, only a finally and thus disposes of the resource for you. If the using statement were to catch all exceptions and continue running it would be a big hindrance to debugging.

Answer (score 0):

It is simply easier and faster to use and read

see for yourself

```
var myVar = null
try
{
    my = new Object();
    //Do stuff
}
finally
{
    if(myVar != null)
        myVar.Dispose()
}
```

vs

```
using(var myVar = new Object())
{
    //Do stuff
}
```

It simply to make sure the *Dispose* is called on that object. The *using* don't do any exception handling as the try/finally don't either